# What is the meaning of "we are sexing one another down" from the movie "Long Shot"(2019)?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is the movie script excerpt.

```
Maggie: I know what’s going on.
Fred: What do you mean?
Maggie: You know what I mean.
Fred: There’s nothing going on.
Maggie: Don’t fucking bullshit me, Fred. ‘Cause my EQ is through the goddamn roof.
  And I understand and intuit the nuances of social dynamics like you wouldn’t 
  believe. The two of you are having sex with each other.
Fred: There’s no way you could discern something like that.
Maggie: Charlotte told me.
Fred: Really?
Maggie: No, but you just did, you fucking idiot.
Fred: Fuck! Shit! That was fucking very clever. Jesus, well, you know what, yes.
   Okay. We’re sexing one another down. So?
Maggie: Ew.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've never seen this usage before - it might even be a complete one-off. But it looks to me like a facetious derivation from *We're **sizing** each other **up*** (checking each other out, forming opinions about each other). They're just seeing how they get on in a very casual sexual relationship.

Comment: ...in fact, it's ***definitely*** a one-off. I just googled "sexing one another down" and got only **2** hits. One was the transcript of the movie, the other seems to be a Chinese site where someone asked about the meaning. Obviously this current ELL question hasn't yet been indexed by Google!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a complete one-off non-standard usage

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Noting that both of us silently switched from ***one another*** to the far more idiomatic ***each other***, I googled again for "sexing **each other** down". Which did actually find a dozen matches, but that's far too few to say it's meaningfully "an English usage". Besides which the fact that the scriptwriters chose to have Fred say ***one another*** rather than ***each other*** makes me think they don't exactly have their finger on the pulse of English! :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, I guess *sexing each other up* ([not *sexing **one another** up*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sexing+one+another+up%2Csexing+each+other+up&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), *please!* :) could be an intermediate step. But presumably that came from *sizing up* anyway.

Comment: Not every question has to be about standard English. Let's stop closing question unnecessarily. Scriptwriters are often looking to avoid cliches.

Comment: I am the OP, and thank you everyone for making comments. My question must be somewhat controversial.  I looked up 'sex down', and the only definition I found was in Urban dictionary as "To engage in intercourse with any female numerous times as primarily a booty call." I thought this definition is not the the right one and not applied here in light of the script context.  Does the 'sex down'  have the same meaning as 'have a sex with someone' and  no other nuances attached except for the fact that it is used by young people?  Thank you very  much.

Comment: @user1026669 "Sex down" is not a common English phrase that I'm aware of. It may be slang in a specific regional dialect? Based on context here, I would assume they mean "we're having casual sex" or "we're having sex but not in a relationship." More common would be to say "we're sleeping together" or "we're hooking up."